# Load external data into an admin model - DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-3.0

Is it possible to load external data into a field for filling in?

Example: A field with for product names. However we already have the names of the products in another location, we just need to list these products within the field in the default django admin. Using resquets.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to customize the Django Admin, right? Check out [this page in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/) for a more detailed explanation, but here's an example that might help:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import *


class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Product
    extra = 0


class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductInline]


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

This will show all of the products attached to a particular order when viewing that order from Django Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepopulate/fill a field in Django Admin with external data source. I guess you have some options defined somewhere outside your Django app and use those options as input for a charfield/integer field.

You can handle filling choices in a seperate Django form or overriding ModelAdmin methods. By creating a seperate form:

```
filter_choices = depends on your logic for loading external data

class AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    filter_text = forms.ChoiceField(choices = filter_choices , label="Filter By", 
                  widget=forms.Select(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel


@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the 'formfield_for_foreignkey' method of the default ModelAdmin class

Example:

> class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
> def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
> if db_field.name == "car":
> kwargs["queryset"] = Car.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
> return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

This example (from the [original docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)) will populate the 'car' field with only specific values.
Pls note that this method suits a foreinKey. I'm not sure if it fits your requirements.